# Bivariate mvncdf for a matrix with different covariance matrices (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I want to do the following:

```
for i = 1:N
    l(i) = mvncdf(x(i,:), mu, sigma(:,:,i))
end
```

Can I do it without a loop given that a covariance matrix is different for each row of x?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Try this:

```
func = @(i) mvncdf(x(i,:), mu, sigma(:,:,i));
l = arrayfun(func, 1:N)
```

This is a neat puzzle-type question, but I'd say that your code with a loop is much more readable and probably just as fast.